# controller isnt loading for the state in ui-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am using ui-route of AngularJS for SPA scenario. 
Short description: there is a general table of customers (home state) which by clicking on cart signs, the user can see the customers order data.(order state)

I have a link that is intended to change my state from home to order while passing some parameters and is working fine. I mean the page of orders is shown, but apparently my order information isn't loading for the tables.

Can somebody give me a hint on how to solve it? thanks

orders.html page

```
    <!-- views/orders.html -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" ng-cloack>
    <h2>Orders</h2>
    <br>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th >Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
        <td>{{$index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{order.product}}</td>
        <td>{{order.total | currency}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

orderController.js file

```
(function() {

var OrdersController = function ($scope, $stateParams) {
      // $routeParams.customerId comes from  routing configuration customerId after PATH       
    var customerId = $stateParams.customerId;
    $scope.orders = null;
    function init() {
        //Search the customers for the customerId
        for (var i=0,len=$scope.customers.length;i<len;i++) {
           if ($scope.customers[i].id === parseInt(customerId)) {
               $scope.orders = $scope.customers[i].orders;
               break;
           }
        }
    }
    $scope.customers = [
        {id:1, joined: '2000-12-02', name:'Ali', city:'Montreal', orderTotal: 9.9956, orders: [ {id: 1, product:'Shoes', total: 9.9956}]},
        {id:2, joined: '1965-01-25',name:'Zoe', city:'Montreal', orderTotal: 19.99, orders: [{id: 2, product:'Baseball', total: 9.995}, {id: 3, product:'Bat', total: 9.9956}]},
        {id:3, joined: '1944-06-15',name:'Tina', city:'Toronto', orderTotal:44.99, orders: [{id: 4, product: 'Headphones', total: 44.99}]},
        {id:4, joined: '1995-03-28',name:'Azad', city:'Vancouver', orderTotal:101.50, orders: [{id: 5, product: 'Kindle', total: 101.50}]}
        ];

    $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
       $scope.sortBy = propName;
       $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
    init();
};

OrdersController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams'];

angular.module('customersApp')
  .controller('OrdersController', OrdersController);
```

}());

and app module file is here:

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('customersApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")
    $stateProvider
        .state('home',
            {
                url:'/',
                controller:'CustomersController',
                templateUrl:'views/customers.html'
            })
        .state('order',{
                url:'/order/:customerId',
                controller: 'OrdersController',
                templateUrl:'views/orders.html'
        });

});
```

}());

Comment: `<a ui-sref="order({ customerId: cust.id })" class="color-violet"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>` is working fine for switching between states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using ui-router you should inject `$stateParams` into controller instead of `$routeParams`.

Injecting `$routeParams` didn't throw an error because you have `ngRoute` module available inside your app.

The reason behind this issue is you are fetching parameter from the URL using `$routeParams` which will we blank in any case, since you are using ui-router `$stateParams` will have that information about the URL params.

```
OrdersController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams'];
```

Changed to

```
OrdersController.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams'];
```

Comment: There is still error with controller: which is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'customerId' of undefined** and doesnt let the browser show the table

Comment: I tried **OrdersController.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams'];**,  after your comment, and  the weird former error is gone. The new one is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'customerId' of undefined** the new one.

Comment: @AliSaberi your controller starting should be `var OrdersController = function ($scope, $stateParams) {` where `$stateParams` will have information about `stateParams`

Comment: Thanks. It's working, now. It was a big starter help for me :)

Comment: @AliSaberi Glad to help you..Thanks :)